# Installing fontconfig from source, says it can't find configure

Tags: configure, fontconfig

I downloaded fontconfig 2.8.0 as part of a chain of downloads trying to fix another issue.

I went into the directory and the INSTALL file said to run:

```
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man
```

Perfectly fine, done that a thousand times. Except:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

So where do I go from here? Never come across this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A) Are you running `./configure` from the proper folder?

(B) Is there a file `configure` in the source folder? If not, you may have to use auto-tools first to create the configure script itself.

(C) How did you download it? This link ought to work: http://fontconfig.org/release/fontconfig-2.8.0.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks. The download at your location had the configure. Installed it and now just need to figure out why Pango can't find the fontconfig or the FreeType backend. One of those fun three hours of sleep sessions.

Comment: For Pango, depending on how/where you are installing things, you may need to make sure pkg-config is reporting the installed packages. I've only installed these things on OS X, though.